# Java конвертер jpg в webp

Tags: java, поиск-библиотек, jpeg, webp

Есть у кого на примете такая библиотека?
опыт преобразования есть у кого?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пожалуйста:

https://bitbucket.org/luciad/webp-imageio

> Java Image I/O reader and writer for the Google WebP image format.

Comment: библиотека заточена под простую конвертацию. а как можно установить параметры сжатия?

Comment: Смотрите здесь: https://bitbucket.org/luciad/webp-imageio/src/085df339fb2f3a96624cb2db2cd70d4d86f2a6bd/src/main/java/com/luciad/imageio/webp/WebPEncoderOptions.java?at=default

Comment: Igor Chubin у тебя есть опыт работы с этой библиотекой? @Igor Chubin