# Как конвертировать byte в BufferedImage?

Tags: java

Есть картинка в виде `byte[]`, если этот массив записать в файл .jpg от будет открываться как нормальный jpg формат.
Необходимо получить из `byte[]` - `BufferedImage`. Перепробовал несколько вариантов, но все возвращают `BufferedImage` заполненный `null`, хотя размеры в `BufferedImage` правильные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот этот метод может считать `BufferedImage` из потока: [javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(java.io.InputStream)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.InputStream))

А вот в этот класс можно обернуть массив байт, чтобы сделать его потоком: [java.io.ByteArrayInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html)

Comment: `byte[] data = pictureData.getData();
     InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
     BufferedImage image = toBufferedImage(ImageIO.read(in));`
я так делал image =  null

Comment: Не тот вариант скопировал. Вот правильны, но он так же не работает
   `byte[] data = pictureData.getData();
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data)
     BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);<br/>`

Comment: If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting stream, null is returned. - Если `ImageIO.read` вернул `null` - значит, формат не распознан. Скажите-ка, какие у вас первые байты в массиве?

Comment: FF 40 E0 00 10  файл с таким началом расспознаётся как jpg

Comment: Сигнатура JPEG - FF D8 FF E0. У вас файл в каком-то другом формате. Чем вы его открываете?

Comment: Прошу прощения,  ...FF D8 FF E0 именно так и начинается (в дебагере десятичные с мин , :) ). делаю так  `byte[] data = pictureData.getData(); InputStream innn = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
 BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(innn);
 ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("y.jpg"));` файл записывается как надо. дебагер показывал в image...data FF FF, вот я и стал на это грешить...видимо проблема  дальше. Пытаюсь решить это [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416357/java-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-jpg-%D0%B2-webp/416360?noredirect=1#comment418023_416360)

Comment: Ну, если `write` записывает после чтения как надо - то и правда проблема дальше. Отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ как решение, если чтение картинки из массива байт и правда работает.